# How do I expand my globe?

Tags: chef-de-bubble

In order to hire Chef Toucan, I need to expand my globe.  Problem is, I have no idea how to do that. I tried looking in various menus, but I am at a total loss.

How do I expand my globe?

Answer (score -2):

Its in the shop you'll have to reach level 11 first though